# Get all rows and colums from array

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm searching for the equivalent of the Python code below in Dart. I need to get the rows and columns from a multidimensional array. How can I achieve this in Dart? I haven't found anything so far.

```
# python
im_rgb = test_image[:, :, [0, 1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most common way to do matrices in Dart is with a List of Lists. To generate one :

```
var matrix = List.generate(rows, (_) => List.generate(columns, (_) => {}));
```

You can then access a cell according to its row and column like this :

```
matrix[row][column];
```